# Animations in my slideshow will play again at the end of a slide

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animations

I've created an autoplaying slideshow of images with a simple fade between each slide. The problem is that each slide seems to 'reload' right before transitioning to the next one. So if I add an animation to a slide e.g. sliding in from the left, image 1 will slide in, then as image 2 is fading in, image 1 will disappear and slide in from the left again. [Here it is on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoaztq2k/), you can see the first image faintly sliding in again as the second appears. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div id="slideshow">

  <div class=slidein-left>
    <img src="https://www.port.ac.uk/-/media/images/news-events-and-blogs/news/2020/october/cat-eyes-closed-600x400.jpg">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0997/4496/files/Untitled_design_19_grande.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slidein-left {
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: slideleft 1s forwards 0.5s;
  animation: slideleft 1s forwards 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideleft {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideleft {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In setInterval :

1. First you're hiding the first image
2. then showing the second image
3. then you append the first image to the slider

the problem is in step 3.
when you append the first image, its display will be block and according to your css when the first image is showing it definitely has "slideleft" animation and before the next cycle begins your first image is showing again.

You can solve this issue by hiding the first image when it placed after the second one:

```
#slideshow > div:not(.slidein-left) + .slidein-left {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Add the code above right above your keyframes in css and you're good to go.

instead of

```
#slideshow > div:not(.slidein-left)
```

you can assign a class to your second div (inside #slideshow) and use .that_class instead.

---

===========================

### Update

Better solution is delaying the step 3.

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)

  setTimeout(function() {$('#slideshow > 
  div:first').appendTo("#slideshow")}, 1000)

}, 3000);
```

and delete the css code that I mentioned before.

It's better to remove the css animation delay because it's ruining the fadeIn effect for image 1.

```
  animation: slideleft 1s forwards;
```

====================

### Update 2

The setTimeout part of the javascript code that I provided in the previous update changed when I uploaded that.

the $("") part of setTimeout function must be in one line and having a newline character (generated by Stackoverflow) in it will ruins the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This seems to solve the problem of image 1 sliding in again, but it still abruptly disappears before image 2 fades in, where I'd like each image to fade into each other.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, you're right. I updated my answer. but make sure you remove the css code in my previous solution.

Comment: I removed your initial CSS and the animation delay, and replaced my jquery with yours but the slideshow isn't playing at all, it's stuck on the first image.

Comment: Well actually it's Stackoverflow's fault. the code was working fine before I update my answer but for some reason Stackoverflow put a new line character after "#slideshow >" in the setTimeout function and ruined the code. I still can't put the setTimeout part in one line. Try put the $('') part of setTimeout in one line and it will work fine. I tested it again in fiddleJs and my local machine and found no problem.

Comment: Haha oh dear. That seems to work perfectly. Thank you very much for your help with this